# array assignment from command output in ksh

Tags: ksh

I wanted to assign the output of a command to an array, but came across the following problem:

```
temp=`<some_command>`
eval set -A array $temp
print $temp
print "***${array[0]},${array[1]}***"
```

The command's output is something like:

```
""
"D"
"M"
"N"
```

In my expectation, `${array[0]}` should be `""`, and `${array[1]}` should be "D".

But, the following is the result:

```
" "D" "M" "N" # $temp
*** D M N,*** # ${array[0]},${array[1]}
```

Just can't figure out how the first element of the array sweeps all of the output. And how to fix it?

Update:
Today, I took another look at the script, and found that the command's output is:

```
" "
"D"
"M"
"N"
```

Note the first line is `" "` (there is a space character in it), instead of a pure empty string `""`.

To start with, the original output was:

```
<some_command> |sort |uniq -c
6421 " "
1090 "D"
   1 "DPV_VALID"
   3 "M"
 588 "N"
  16 "S"
6382 "Y"
```

I always thought the first line was a pure empty string, e.g. `""`, didn't realize that there is a space character in the double quotes.

Then, I used `awk` to get the 2nd field:

```
<some_command> |sort |uniq -c |awk '{print $2}'
```

The output became:

```
"
"D"
"M"
"N"
```

That's the cause of later mess-up of the command `eval set -A` (`awk` uses space character as the delimiter by default). If it were a pure empty string, it would have worked.

It also works if I re-write the command as:

```
temp=`<some_command> |sort |uniq -c |sed 's/" "$/""/' |awk '{print $2}'`
eval set -A array $temp
```

Still, glenn's solution is also pretty neat. Thanks!

Comment: What value does `$IFS` hold when you set the array? Why do you think you need `eval`?

Comment: @glennjackman Sorry, what is `$IFS`? I need `eval` because I only want the content inside the double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the quotes, just remove them. You don't have to resort to `eval`

```
temp='""
"D"
"M"
"N"'
set -A array $temp
for (( i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++ )); do
    echo "$i:${array[i]}"
done
for (( i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++ )); do
    array[i]=${array[i]#\"}   # remove a leading quote
    array[i]=${array[i]%\"}   # remove a trailing quote
done
for (( i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++ )); do
    echo "$i:${array[i]}"
done
```

outputs

```
0:""
1:"D"
2:"M"
3:"N"
0:   
1:D
2:M
3:N
```

tested with ksh93

Comment: Thanks, this works! Still, I am not sure why `eval` would mess it up.